# Material2: How to override the Roboto font in Material2's components

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I would like to use Lato instead. I tried adding it in the `index.html` and `styles.css` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

The best way I found was to target all Angular Material 2 selectors as below:

```
body [class^='mat-'], body [class*=' mat-'] {
    font-family: "lato";
}
```

This is because angular 2 components all have a class starting with 'mat-'.

Comment: Note: There is typo above. [class*=' mat-'] has a extra space that stops it working

Comment: Actually the ^ selects classes beginning with, and the * selects all; i.e. in this case subsequent, so I think this is correct, have you got an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: You are looking at the first one, not the second one.

When I used this snippet I did exactly as I said and it worked.

Comment: The space is deliberate as it targets the classes that aren't first i the class list, I may misunderstand your point. Is there a possible scenario where this doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure; for me it didn't work unless I removed the space.

Answer (score 5):

To build on @Ben Taliadoros' answer, this will keep material icons from breaking:

```
body [class^='mat-'], body [class*=' mat-'] {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
} 

body .material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

**CSS Syntax info:**

- [attribute^=value]    *Selects every element whose attribute begins with value*
- [attribute*=value]    *Selects every element whose attribute contains the value*

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

Create your own scss file and define font-family like this

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
    $font-family: 'Lato'
);

@include mat-core($custom-typography);
```

checked out the [Typography Customization](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/typography.md#customization)

Comment: if you are using a custom theme file where you define your themes anyways this is a nice solution imho

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem @kyw. The only way currently is to override the font in each component where needed.

After adding this replaced some fonts in components:

```
html * {
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Hopefully somebody can give us a better hint.

Answer (score 1):

This works and does not clobber the mat-icon font.

```
// Override Material Design Roboto Font
body [class^='mat-']:not(mat-icon), body [class*='mat-']:not(mat-icon)  {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Felt few would read comments, so submitting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

(For anyone else looking this up using angular material version 12.0.1) In the default generated custom-theme.scss create a "custom typography".
Similar to Tarn's answer but had to make a couple slight changes to get it to work.

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;

$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Lato'
);

@include mat.core($custom-typography);
```